# undefined symbol: ap_array_str_contains

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

I am trying to run Apache on Amazon Linux with SSL for my website and I configured all ssl prerequisites. But when I start the Apache it throws the error saying:

```
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 58 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: ap_array_str_contains
```

conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf file contains:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Apache httpd version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Amazon)
```

I installed mod_ssl using:

```
yum install mod24_ssl
```

I am not aware how to troubleshoot this; I am pretty new to apache.

Please let me know if anyone could help?